# Paginating data from Smart contract in Solidity

Tags: pagination, solidity

I have a smart contract that uses mapping to store data in it. I want to paginate the data mapping.

I have the following Smart contract.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

contract Pagination {
    uint public stringCount;
    mapping (uint => string) public strings;

    function add(string memory item) public {
        stringCount++;
        strings[stringCount]=item;
    }
}
```

I also want to know the best practice out there.

The two approaches in my mind are:

1. Get the total count of items in the mapping in the front-end application and implement the pagination logic there and load only specific items from the mapping.
2. Implement the pagination logic in the smart contract (something like what we have been doing in Web2)

**Note:** I have gone through some questions about paginations on StackOverflow but they all are regarding the arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Approach 1 - Analysis

You can get the total count via
`const stringCount = await contractInstance.methods.stringCount().call();` and then implement pagination on frontend.
If you go via this approach, you'll have to call smart contract to fetch string one by one.

### Approach 2 - Analysis

Let's say you have a function like:

```
function getStrings(uint startIndex, uint endIndex) view public returns (string[] memory) 
  { 
    // logic goes in here 
  }
```

Here you will be making only one 2 calls for fetching whole page. First request for getting `stringCount` and then only 1 request again for next strings.

#### So, the second approach is better.